# JasperReports: Removing duplicate values from dataset

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to print only unique values from a dataset into the list component, avoiding duplicate values.

How to do it?

P.S. I am using XML as the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following when you are selecting nodes in you datasource using X-Path.

```
/root/*[not(text() = preceding-sibling::*/text())]
```

It will select unique nodes for a XML structure like bellow.

```
<root>
      <Node1>Data1</Node1>
      <Node2>Data2</Node2>
      <Node1>Data1</Node1>
      <Node2>Data2</Node2>
      <Node3>Data3</Node3>
</root>
```

Comment: I am using XML as the data source.

Comment: I dont want unique nodes, I want unique values from same nodes. 
For eg. <Product>Prod1</Product> 
        <Product>Prod1</Product> 
        <Product>Prod2</Product> 
        <Product>Prod2</Product> ]
Should return Prod1 and Prod2 only once, even though they appear twice in the xml data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can group on that value, in your case the `Product`, grouping will eliminate duplicates.

NOTE: the data should be sorted for grouping to work